# Personal favourite and recent call list for android

Tags: android, calllog

I been trying out the other tutorials on the call log and favourite. But this method is always using the native android phonebook. Is there any way to make a favourite call list and recent call list just personal to my app (only my app can use it)? Any help/leads would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code to get recent call list:

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
String strOrder = CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC";
Cursor cur = cr.query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, selection, null,
                    strOrder);
```

also here is a code to get your favorite contacts:

```
Cursor starred = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null,ContactsContract.Contacts._ID + " = " + contactId + "AND" + ContactsContract.Contacts.STARRED + "= 1" ,null, null);
```

Hope this will help you.